# Why might mutt email be accepted/rejected by windows recipient as a function of alphabetic string content in the body of html file being sent?

Tags: mutt

Calling mutt-1.5.24 on linux.

I'm seeing some very odd behavior when emailing an html file from linux to windows/outlook using mutt on linux.  Example of the mutt call...

```
mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s 'yuk, yuk, yuk' 'moe.howard@stooge.com' < a.html
```

The email does not show up on the windows side.  mutt returned no error or warning on the linux side.  Now, here's the odd part...  If I global/replace the string "pcie" in the body of the html to "pcix", the email appears on the windows/outlook side just fine.  OR... if I global/replace "ity" to "..." it also works fine (even if I leave "pcie" alone).  But changing "ity" to "xxx" fails.  Very odd character sensitivity behavior like this.

In my home dir on the linux side I see a file ~/sent getting created.  The header (whether the email made it to the windows/outlook side or not) looks like...

```
From m.howard@theserver.stooge.com Thu Jan 28 18:49:29 2021
Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2021 18:49:29 -0500
From: Moe Howard <mhoward@theserver.stooge.com>
To: moe.howard@stooge.com
Subject: yuk, yuk, yuk
Message-ID: <20210128234929.GA48266@atletx7-reg062.amd.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
User-Agent: Mutt/1.5.24 (2015-08-30)
Status: RO
Content-Length: 20537
Lines: 122

<html>  
....etc... the rest of the html which firefox reads just fine if I get rid of the header above
```

Grasping at straws.  Looking at the "charset=us-ascii" in the "sent" file thinking it should be something else ?  So I tried providing other options by adding "-e 'set assumed_charset=utf-8:us-ascii'" to the command.  No luck.

Any ideas what might be happening and what a solution might be ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  All my email actually arrived in Outlook.  It's just that it got sent to the junk folder, labeled as spam.  So if the body of the html contains "pcie", it's spam.  But "pcix" is not.  Got to go undo that now.